# How can I remove text duplicates in a cell string?

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

So imagine there is the following string in a cell in excel:

```
A1 = "Company 1 Company 2 Company 1 Company 2 Company 3"
```

and the desired result for now is removing the duplicates:

`A1 = "Company 1 Company 2 Company 3"` (I imagine that this one doesn't require a macro)

the ideal one would be to put the distinct values in different cells in a vertical way:

```
A1 = "Company 1"
A2 = "Company 2"
A3 = "Company 3"
```

(which would require definitely programming but since I never used vba i'm not experienced enough I think to elaborate such code)

Is it feasible?

EDIT: the delimiter can be changed from a space " " to other, for example, a semicolon ";" to prevent errors and to be easier to solve this one.

Comment: Your sample data is too simple and the delimiter is reused where the data should not be split.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what do you mean the data is simple? (don't know if I should have said but A1 happening thousands of times, and each time is refereed to a different id ). Also, could you please clarify the problem with the delimiter? Is it because several spaces are happening inside the name and the next one? I think I can change the concatenate function that used to give the output on A1 to separate them by comma... would that help?

Comment: Only if there is never a comma inside a company name.

Comment: @Jeeped is 100% right. Split values that uses spaces or commas as delimiters, sometimes, can cause trouble if the values themselves contains spaces or commas. If you can customize the concatenation, I sugges you to use a really weird delimiter. For example, use `||` (Alt GR +1) and then mayb we can work something out

Comment: @Jeeped I checked the names, only 2 company names have the comma inside, bad luck. Nonetheless, given the input you gave, then it should be used a delimiter that isn't used in the company names... would that help, for example, by using a semicolon? ( I have checked that they don't have a ";" in their names)

Comment: You got four valid answers - could you try them? It would be *helpful for other users*, too if you marked one as your solution or upvote helpful answers.

Comment: As I said i'm not familiar with VBA, i tried some of them but didn't work. Maybe I could not adapt them to my problem very well. Thanks all for the anwsers. I have tried a diferrent approach, I copied he columns of the 2 entities and removed the duplicated ones and got in the end the same reference for different companies, which was what I wanted somehow.

Comment: If one has Excel 2013 and further you could get an array returned through: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")`. Excel O365 even spills the array down.

Answer (score 1):

Asumption is you have a delimiter between the strings to tell apart you could use the following code

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Const SEPARATOR = ","
Dim vDat As Variant

    vDat = Split(Range("A1"), SEPARATOR)

    ' remove trailing blanks if necessary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
        vDat(i) = Trim(vDat(i))
    Next i

    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim vItem As Variant

    For Each vItem In vDat
        If Not dic.Exists(vItem) Then
            dic.Add vItem, vItem
        End If
    Next

    vDat = dic.Keys

    ' Write data to column B
    Range("B1").Resize(UBound(vDat) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vDat)

    'Debug.Print Join(vDat, SEPARATOR)

End Sub
```

Tested with the following data

```
A1 = Company 1,  Company 2, Company 1, Company 2 , Company 3
```

or

```
A1 = IBM,  Apple, Microsoft, Apple , IBM
```

Answer (score 0):

With an unambiguous string, and by that I mean:

- delimiter not included in the substrings,  **OR**
- each entry surrounded by double quotes

you can use `Power Query` in Excel 2010, 2013 or `Data Get & Transform` in Excel 2016, to do all of that.

- Split the cell on the delimiter

  - Define the quote mark as the text qualifier if necessary
- Rows - remove duplicates

So with data like:

```
Company 1;Company 2;Company 1;Company 2;Company 3
```

or (space delimiter)

```
"Company 1" "Company 2" "Company 1" "Company 2" "Company 3"
```

you can easily accomplish what you require without using VBA.

And if, as in your examples, there are extraneous spaces at the beginning or end of the data, Power Query has a `Text.Trim` function that will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution using UDF (commented for clarity):

```
Public Function UNIQUELIST(ByVal arg_vOriginalList As String, ByVal arg_sDelimiter As String, ByVal arg_lReturnIndex As Long) As Variant

    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim vElement As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Use a dictionary to extract unique elements
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    i = 0   'This is a counter to keep track until we reach the appropriate return index

    'Loop through each element
    For Each vElement In Split(arg_vOriginalList, arg_sDelimiter)
        'Check the trimmed, lowercase element against the keys of the dictionary
        If Not oDict.Exists(LCase(Trim(vElement))) Then
            'Unique element found
            i = i + 1
            If i = arg_lReturnIndex Then
                'Found appropriate unique element, output and exit function
                UNIQUELIST = Trim(vElement)
                Exit Function
            End If

            'Not correct return index, add element to dictionary
            'Lowercase the key (so uniques aren't case sensitive) and trim both the key and the value
            oDict.Add LCase(Trim(vElement)), Trim(vElement)
        End If
    Next vElement

    'arg_lReturnIndex was less than 1 or greater than the number of unique values, return blank
    UNIQUELIST = vbNullString

End Function
```

Then in a cell where you want the output to start (for example, B1), put this formula and copy down (adjust the `","` to be the correct delimiter):

```
=UNIQUELIST($A$1,",",ROW(A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach using same delimiters as in OP**

I assume the **same space delimiters** as in your *original post*: As you want to get your company strings in groups of **two**, I slightly modified the good solution of @Storax by concatenating the `Split` result in steps of 2 first and demonstrate a shorter way to write results back to sheet (cf. section [5]).

**Example Code**

```
Option Explicit                ' declaration head of your code module

Sub SplitCompanies()
' [0] declare variables and set objects
  Dim v, vItem
  Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
  Dim s, str As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle5")  ' << change to your sheet name
  Dim dict As Object                            ' late binding of dictionary
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' [1] get cell value and split it (space delimited as in Original Post)
  str = ws.Range("A1")        ' cell value, e.g. "Company 1 Company 2 Company 1 Company 2 Company 3"
  s = Split(str, " ")         ' split cell value (space delimiter)
' [2] count all companies and redimension helper array
  n = Int((UBound(s) + 1) / 2) - 1    ' items counter equals 1/2 of split items
  ReDim v(0 To n)             ' redim zero-based 1-dim helper array
' [3] concatenate partial strings in helper array
  For i = 0 To n
    v(i) = s(i * 2) & " " & s(i * 2 + 1)
  Next i
' [4] build dictionary with unique items
  For Each vItem In v
    If Not dict.Exists(vItem) Then
        dict.Add vItem, vItem
    End If
  Next
' [5] Write data to column B
  ws.Range("B1:B" & dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
' [6] clear memory
  Set dict = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```